# Populating a dropdownlist onchange event of another in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can this be achieve?

[image]

The above grid is generated with `ng-repeat`

I want when a subject on a particular row is selected it populate the teachers dropdown on the same row.

Teachers XML:

```
<ArrayOfTeacherToSubject xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DTO">
<TeacherToSubject>
<ClassName i:nil="true"/>
<ClassToClassArmId i:nil="true"/>
<ModifiedBy i:nil="true"/>
<ModifiedOn i:nil="true"/>
<SchoolId>0</SchoolId>
<StaffId>20</StaffId>
<StaffName>David Jumma</StaffName>
<SubjectId>4</SubjectId>
<SubjectName i:nil="true"/>
<TeacherToSubjectId i:nil="true"/>
</TeacherToSubject>
<TeacherToSubject>
<ClassName i:nil="true"/>
<ClassToClassArmId i:nil="true"/>
<ModifiedBy i:nil="true"/>
<ModifiedOn i:nil="true"/>
<SchoolId>0</SchoolId>
<StaffId>20</StaffId>
<StaffName>David Jumma</StaffName>
<SubjectId>6</SubjectId>
<SubjectName i:nil="true"/>
<TeacherToSubjectId i:nil="true"/>
</TeacherToSubject>
<TeacherToSubject>
<ClassName i:nil="true"/>
<ClassToClassArmId i:nil="true"/>
<ModifiedBy i:nil="true"/>
<ModifiedOn i:nil="true"/>
<SchoolId>0</SchoolId>
<StaffId>20</StaffId>
<StaffName>David Jumma</StaffName>
<SubjectId>3</SubjectId>
<SubjectName i:nil="true"/>
<TeacherToSubjectId i:nil="true"/>
</TeacherToSubject>
</ArrayOfTeacherToSubject>
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-repeat creates a new scope for every iteration so you can use the fact that both controls are under the same scope to select the teachers.

I'm presuming you want something like this in the teachers select:

```
teacher.key as teacher.name for teacher in teachers[subject.id]
```

Comment: Can you illustrate with an example?

Comment: I tried your example and it did not work. Both the subject and teacher dropdown are binded to a web api call. I edited and added the result of the teachers web api call.

Comment: I added an xml to the question.

Comment: I meant could you setup the example at plnkr.com like I did? So I could see clearly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a directive with an isolated scope for each row.

2) bind your "subject select" with a scope item `ng-model="subjectSelected"`

3) Inside your directive's controller, add a watch to this model

```
$scope.$watch('subjectSelected', function(newVal, oldVal){
    //
});
```

4) Inside the previous function, assign a new array to an object `$scope.options`

5) for the binding to your view, you can use the directive `ng-options`

```
<select ng-model="$parent.contactTypeHomeHost" ng-options="option.id as option.label for option in options"></select>
```

Comment: Hello. Can you please give an example.

Comment: could you please give more information than just "it dit not work"?

Comment: I created an Isolated scope for each row using a directive and added a `$watch` to know when the subject changes to populate the teachers dropdown within the `$watch` function.